# jJenkins - Empty workspace after build

Tags: maven, jenkins, workspace, cobertura

I have setup Jenkins with Maven but I am having trouble populating my workspace directory after a build.  I get a build success but my workspace directory remains empty?  The builds are correctly saving to the builds folder but for some unknown reason, are not copying files to workspace.

I am running on a Mac (created the scm.sh shell to run scm) and fear that this could be the problem?  When I try to 'Wipe Out Workspace' in Jenkins I get a:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scm": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 'Populating workspace directory after a build' - what are you trying to do? Workspace directory usually should be 'populated' before the build - by automatically (or in rare cases manually) checking out or copying things into it. The build then runs from the workspace as its home directory. If it is configured in such a way as not to write things into the workspace - then it won't, there is no crime in it.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply.  I'm generating a coverage.xml with Cobertura per build.  I'm trying to get the plugin to locate the generated .xml but cannot as it's not being copied into the 'workspace' directory.  Switching off the cobertura plugin (which is breaking the build due to not locating the coverage.xml in 'workspace') results in a successful build but, once again, the 'workspace' directory remains empty?

Comment: Please add this info to your question as it is essential. Also, please specify how you configured Cobertura plugin in your build.